# Blazor Server cannot find static assets of an RCL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server project that has an RCL:

1. When I run this project from `Visual Studio Preview`, the app runs fine.
2. If I `publish the project` to a folder, the app cannot find static assets of the RCL (error in the browser console - 404 CSS not found)
3. If I run this project from the `non-preview version of Visual Studio`, I still have the same problem

So it seems that only Visual Studio Preview is being able to run this correctly

The project has the following structure

- Common Utility Library (C# DLL) - `Utility`
- Common User Interface Component Library (Blazor RCL) - `CommonUI`
- Core Business Logic Library (C# DLL) - `Core`
- Blazor Server Web Application (Blazor Server Application) - `WebApp`

`CommonUI` has some static assets (css+js).
The dependency of the projects among each other is as follows:

- `Utility`: None
- `CommonUI` : `Utility`
- `Core` : `Utility`
- `WebApp` : `Utility`,`Core` and `CommonUI`

I am using `.net8`

Comment: I also need to upgrade vs to run .net8 project. How about using `dotnet run` and `dotnet publish` by CLI.